# Rails web shop with Devise login and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am making a web shop application in Rails with Devise as a login gem. The structure is as follows:
A user table which has a basket_id column and in its model I have set `has_one :basket`
The basket table `belongs_to :user`

In my basket_controller.rb I want to use the create method to get the user

```
  # POST /baskets
  # POST /baskets.json
 def create
   @basket = Basket.new(basket_params)
   @basket.user_id = current_user.id

   respond_to do |format|
     if @basket.save
       format.html { redirect_to @basket, notice: 'Basket was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @basket }
    else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @basket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the current_user method that should be automatically generated by Devise is not found and therefore the user_id in the Baskets table is not set. Also I have no idea where would I set the basket_id in the Users table or this should be done automatically because of the relationship defined in the models?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: with `has_one`, you don't have a `basket_id` defined in the user table. And for your problem, have you checked that the user is actually authenticated ?

Comment: I know has_one doesn't define it, but I have added it with a migration, so it has a place to store the id.  The user is authenticated because when I go to /users/sign_in it sends a message that I am already logged in.

Comment: Could you post the error you get?

Comment: @MZokov the fact that you added it with a migration won't make it magically appear AFAIK.
Have you tested that it's not another validation error ?

Answer (score 0):

For **current_user** to work you need to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your controller. If that does not work maybe is a `csrf` problem that you can solve placing

```
= csrf_meta_tags
```

In your layout.

Comment: `authenticate_user!` is not required to access `current_user` and `csrf_meta_tags` is only required for the devise session controller, which has it by default.

Comment: If authenticate_user! is not required then it should be the user_signed_in? method. Does that sound right? Ideally I would like to be able to use the current_user without necessary authentication.